# What's the best way to tell if an adjective is being applied to one or two conjuncts?

Tags: grammar

For e.g, is blue ice and tea, just normal everyday tea with blue ice, or is it blue tea with blue ice?

This issue of mine actually came up in a real life scenario (well, many actually):

''singular verbs and pronouns are normal: The team is away this weekend; they have a good chance of winning.''

I spent a good 5 minutes trying to figure out how on earth 'they' is a singular pronoun, then I realized it actually meant a singular verb, and a plural pronoun, because it wouldn't make sense otherwise (hence my confusion).

Whilst obvious to me now in this case, sometimes it's virtually impossible to tell the difference because both scenarios seem equally likely. This is especially true in complicated writings, where you have to rely less on human context and more on logic and reason.

Comment: Context is everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a writer, I use the following rule:

- If only the ice is blue, I write "tea and blue ice".  No possibility of ambiguity.
- If both the ice and the tea are blue (and "blue tea and blue ice" is not an option), then I use "blue tea and ice".  There is some chance the user will get it wrong, but there are no remaining alternatives.

For a reader, there is no ironclad way to tell, so if context and common sense won't tell me, I assume the writer is using the same rule I use when I write.

Comment: Wow, that is really good. It seems so simple but it's really effective. See blue tea and ice sounds better than blue tea and blue ice, but of course, there's no standard when it comes to this, so there's always ambiguity. But damn it there should be, and this should be it!

Comment: Sometimes the repetition can serve prosodic as well as prosaic purposes.  Consider a phrase like "violent lives and violent deaths" and "dreary days and dreary nights": when the two nouns are naturally in opposition, using the same adjective creates a vivid continuity.